# Logarithms and regression

Tags: regression

I have a regression where I am trying to predict Y, using several variables. My variables are A, B, C.

[image]

I'm using `R` for my analysis. My equation is as follows:

```
mod <-lm(  log(Y/B) ~ log(A/B) + log(A/C), data = dataframe)
```

and a summary of the model is as follows:

```
Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          -1.326698   0.080683  -16.44   <2e-16 ***
log(A/B)              0.756779   0.007507  100.81   <2e-16 ***
log(A/C)             -0.292373   0.012762  -22.91   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.6925 on 17063 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.4043, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4042 
F-statistic:  5790 on 2 and 17063 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

I understand that `log(j/k) = log(j) - log(k)`; so `log(Y/B)` can be written similarly.
Is there a way that I can include the `B` variable in the dependent part of my regression equation?

Also, it is acceptable to use a variable for normalizing, on both dependent and independent variables? I have seen other examples where the same variable is used in this way, but I was not certain if this makes sense.

Comment: As it is, $−\log(B)$ appears on both sides of the regression equation and so is redundant - whatever coefficient appeared in front of $\log(B)$ would actually be 1 unit too small. Also $\log(A)$ appears twice on the right hand side. Is this what you intended?

Comment: If I write the LHS as `log(Y) - log(B)`, the R-sq remains the same. If I write the RHS as (log(A) - log(B)) + log(A/C) the R-sq changes (though I don't understand why). I intended to include `log(A)` twice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By virtue of properties of logarithms, the **original model**,

$$\log(Y/B) = \beta_0 + \beta_1\log(A/B) + \beta_2\log(A/C) + \varepsilon$$

($\varepsilon$ is a zero - mean random variable) can be written

$$\log(Y) - \log(B) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 (\log(A)-\log(B)) + \beta_2(\log(A)-\log(C)) + \varepsilon,$$

which algebraically is *identical* to

$$\log(Y) = \beta_0 + (\beta_1+\beta_2)\log(A) + (1-\beta_1)\log(B) - \beta_2\log(C) + \varepsilon.$$

Note particularly that nothing funny has happened to the random term $\varepsilon$, so that fitting one (via least squares or maximum likelihood) will give the same results as fitting the other.

Conversely, if you start with the **general model**

$$\log(Y) = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1\log(A) + \gamma_2\log(B) + \gamma_3\log(C) + \delta,$$

comparing coefficients shows that $\gamma_0 = \beta_0$, $\delta = \varepsilon$, and

$$\gamma_1 + \gamma_2 + \gamma_3 = (\beta_1+\beta_2) + (1-\beta_1) + (-\beta_2) = 1.$$

These are the only relations among the coefficients, as evidenced by the fact you can recover the betas from the gammas in many ways such as

$$\beta_1 = 1 - \gamma_2, \quad \beta_2 = -\gamma_3 \quad \text{or}$$

$$\beta_1 = \gamma_1 + \gamma_3, \quad \beta_2 = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 -1,$$

for example.

Thus **the original model is the general model with a single linear constraint**.  Either method will result in equivalent fits and the same parameter estimates.  Therefore,

1. Yes, there is a way to include $B$ as an independent variable, as shown; and
2. The original model makes sense.

Comment: I am considering the $R^2$ in both models, and in the first case the $R^2$ is much higher (0.4 compared to 0.07). I understand your clear explanation, but I'm struggling to understand why the $R^2$ is so different, if the model structures are similar. Is it a sign that my variables are not heteroskedastic?

Comment: While you are correct, Macro's example with independent variables is important to consider. While the constrained model is predictive, it is difficult to tell whether it is only due to the trivial/artificial effect of having $-log(B)$ on both sides, or there is a deeper relationship.

Comment: @Aniko I don't understand your remark, because both Celenius' model and the linearly constrained model provide exactly the same inferences; they are related merely by a (linear) change of parameterization.  Perhaps you could expand on your point?

Comment: @celenius In this context (where one model is nested in the other with a common set of data), $R^2$ is directly (although negatively) related to the mean squared residual.  The algebra shows the residuals will be the same, whence $R^2$ must be the same in either formulation (that is, your original one or the linearly constrained one).  Am I misunderstanding what you mean by "both models" and "the first case"?

Comment: @whuber, the $R^2$ is different for each model. When I use the `original model` it is $0.4042$; when I use the `general model` it is 0.07. (to clarify, by first case I meant `original model`)

Comment: @celenius There's an error there: $R^2$ *cannot* decrease for the general model, because it's more flexible than the original one.  I think you haven't fit the general model, but have fit something else.

Comment: Could it be due to a linear relationship not existing between variables?

Comment: @celenius No, I think it's likely a mistake using the software :-(.  Have you plotted the usual diagnostic graphs (such as a scatterplot of residuals vs. predicted values) for both fits?

Comment: Hmm, it's definitely possible I'm making a mistake using the software, but it's quite straightforward to re-organize so I think I'm doing everything correctly. I have been examining the residuals - but as there are so many data points it's a bit hard to spot anything incorrect.

Comment: @celenius Make a scatterplot of residuals for one model versus residuals for another.  If the models are the same, you'll get the usual diagonal lineup of points.  Otherwise the plot will show you where the fit is improving and where it's getting worse.

Comment: @whuber But celenius is not fitting the general model with a constraint: he is talking about the four-parameter version. These will not provide the same fit. Also, if in the correct 4-parameter model $\gamma_2=0$, then from your formulas $\beta_1=1$, so any test of it being equal to 0 should be rejected. The lack of relationship in the "usual sense" leads to a significant effect in the smaller model.

Comment: @Aniko I beg to differ: please reread the original question.  That's a three parameter model, with one for the constant, one for $\log(A/B)$, and the third for $\log(A/C)$, as listed under "Coefficients" in the output.  In this model, $\gamma_1+\gamma_2+\gamma_3=1$ is the constraint, not $\gamma_2=0$.

Comment: @whuber Sorry for being confusing. Yes, celenius is fitting the smaller model in the post. But I suppose he wants to conclude something from its results, for example that $Y$ is predicted by $A, B, C$ somehow (per his first sentence). The point I am trying to make is that $\log(Y/B)$ is _always_ predicted by $\log(A/B)$, even if all the variables are independent.

Comment: @Aniko Perhaps I'm the one who's confused.  It seems to me that when $\log(Y)$ is predicted as $\widehat{\log(Y)}$ in terms of independent variables $A$, $B$, and $C$ (either the "full" or constrained model), then one immediately obtains the prediction for $\log(Y/B)$ as $\widehat{\log(Y)} - \log(B)$.  I just don't see what point you're making.  We can continue in chat if you would like to clear up my puzzlement (but please expect delays--I can't do it in real time today).

Answer (score 1):

Just doing

$$ \log(Y) \sim \log(A) + \log(B) + \log(C) $$

would be equivalent to the model you're fitting, under the constraint that the coefficients sum to 1 (thanks whuber for making this clear). The coefficients would be changed to compensate for the redundancies in your current formulation, but the fit would be the same.

**Edit:** If you ignore the constraint and fit the model above then note that the $R^2$ value will change (and typically be much lower) when compared to your original formulation. This is because $B$ appears on both sides of the regression function, so there may appear to be an impressive $R^2$ regardless of whether $Y$ relates to $A,B,C$. See

```
A=runif(100)
B=runif(100)
C=runif(100)
Y=runif(100)

g1 = lm( log(Y/B) ~ log(A/B) + log(A/C))
g2 = lm( log(Y) ~ log(A)+log(B)+log(C))
```

as an example. Clearly none of the variables are related to each other, but model g1 shows a pretty impressive $R^2$ (around $45\%$ in my simulation).

Comment: I think this is part of my confusion - when I used the model you suggested, the fit is not the same; the `R-sq` value is now 0.07. I'm going to update my question showing a plot of all of the variables.

Comment: What you have now is $\log(Y/B) \sim \log(A/B) + \log(A/C)$. This is the same as $\log(Y)-\log(B) \sim \log(A)-\log(B)+\log(A)-\log(C)$. So, $\log(A),\log(B),\log(C)$ are all still in the model. The coefficient of $\log(B)$ should just be shifted by 1, that for $\log(A)$ should be doubled, and that for $\log(C)$ should be negative what it was before.

Comment: The $R^2$ will change. This is because $B$ appears on both the left and right side of the regression equation originally. I was only saying the relationship between $Y$ and the rest of the variables will not change. This is important enough to add as an edit to the main post.

Comment: I think I understand - so is it incorrect to use $B$ on both sides of the equation?

Comment: It's incorrect in the sense that it may lead one to believe something is going on when there truly isn't if $R^2$ is used as a guide.

Comment: Thanks @Macro, I had fallen into this trap of believing something was going on.

Comment: Your claim that $\log(Y) \sim \log(A) + \log(B) + \log(C)$ is equivalent to $\log(Y/B) \sim \log(A/B) + \log(A/C)$ is obviously false: the former requires three parameters and the latter only two (in addition to the implied constant).

Comment: @whuber - I believe the **effective number of parameters** are the same due to redundancies inherent to replicating the same variable multiple times on one or both sides of the regression function. I will post an edit later displaying (or not) the equivalent fit between the two models.

Comment: $\log(Y) - \log(B)$ = $\beta_0 + \beta_1 (\log(A)-\log(B)) + \beta_2(\log(A)-\log(C)) + \varepsilon$ implies $\log(Y) = \beta_0 + (\beta_1+\beta_2)\log(A) + (1-\beta_1)\log(B) - \beta_2\log(C) + \varepsilon$, forcing a nontrivial linear relation among the coefficients of $\log(A)$, $\log(B)$, and $\log(C)$ (they must sum to unity).  Naturally, $R^2$ will increase when you relax that relation.  @celenius: this answers your first question.

Comment: @whuber, as you point out in your answer, "Note particularly that nothing funny has happened to the random term ε, so that fitting one (via least squares or maximum likelihood) will give the same results as fitting the other." - that's all I meant in my post when I said "The coefficients would be changed to compensate for the redundancies in your current formulation, but the fit would be the same." - so I can see that we don't actually disagree.

Comment: But if we agree, you must conclude the opposite of what you have written!  $\log(Y) \sim \log(A) + \log(B) + \log(C)$ is *not* equivalent to @Celenius' model.  In fact, your more general model is nested within Celenius' model; it effectively adds one more parameter; it will not decrease, and usually increase, $R^2$; and you cannot estimate Celenius' parameters from its parameter estimates.

Comment: But you just said that the two provide the same fit. Is that not equivalence in some sense? I understand that one is over-identified version of the other and that they are not equivalent in that way, but they are equivalent in terms of the fit which is all I meant (as it was all that seemed relevant).

Comment: The two that provide the same fit are (1) @Celenius' original model and (2) the general model *with the linear constraint.*  If you don't apply the constraint--which is not mentioned in your reply--you will get a different (better) fit and a higher $R^2$.